# Google Chrome Extension - How to generate a browser action without clicking?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension.

I found the fact that we have to click on the "icon" to generate a browser action tedious.

Is there a way for us to call a function ( using javascript ) that could generate a browser action so that we do not need to click anymore?

Comment: No it is **not** possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, chrome doesn't give the way to do that.
Because popup is for user interaction.

a popup cannot open by any action but clicking on it manually. 
If you want to open as a popup, you have to open that popup as a new tab with:

`chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')})`

Which will run the exact same way as the popup but not within a popup.

Comment: OP question is about calling `browser action` popup without manual clicking!

Comment: have edited : It's not possible, chrome doesn't give the way to do that.
Because popup is for user interaction.

Comment: Thanks! I will open the pop up with a new tab then!

Answer (score 0):

**The required API is now there, HOWEVER it's still experimental behind a flag:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/openPopup

> From version 67: this feature is behind the #extension-apis preference
>   (needs to be set to Enabled). To change preferences in Chrome, visit
>   chrome://flags.

Firefox supports this since 57 version.

Also this can be called only from a [handler of some user action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/User_actions).